# Debugging just_audio on iOS

Tags: flutter, just-audio

This is more of a general question, but is there any way to get system/player logs from just_audio on iOS? On Android, I can see Exoplayer logs but on iOS playback just silently fails if something goes wrong, such as files not being found or network errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature in just_audio to enable/disable system logs, partly because on the Android side there is actually no way to control all of those logs. But it sounds like what you really want is not the logs, but a just_audio API to be notified of network errors. The README explains how to be notified of such errors, but if nothing's happening on iOS, you should report the issue on the GitHub page.